# retain_graph problem with GRU in Pytorch 1.6

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am aware that, while employing `loss.backward()` we need to specify `retain_graph=True` if there are multiple networks and multiple loss functions to optimize each network separately. But even with (or without) specifying this parameter I am getting errors. Following is an MWE to reproduce the issue (on PyTorch 1.6).

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)


class GRU1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GRU1, self).__init__()
        self.brnn = nn.GRU(input_size=2, bidirectional=True, num_layers=1, hidden_size=100)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.brnn(x)


class GRU2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GRU2, self).__init__()
        self.brnn = nn.GRU(input_size=200, bidirectional=True, num_layers=1, hidden_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.brnn(x)

gru1 = GRU1()
gru2 = GRU2()
gru1_opt = optim.Adam(gru1.parameters())
gru2_opt = optim.Adam(gru2.parameters())
criterion = nn.MSELoss()


for i in range(100):
    gru1_opt.zero_grad()
    gru2_opt.zero_grad()
    vector = torch.randn((15, 100, 2))
    gru1_output, _ = gru1(vector)  # (15, 100, 200)
    loss_gru1 = criterion(gru1_output, torch.randn((15, 100, 200)))
    loss_gru1.backward(retain_graph=True)
    gru1_opt.step()
    gru1_output, _ = gru1(vector)  # (15, 100, 200)
    gru2_output, _ = gru2(gru1_output)  # (15, 100, 2)
    loss_gru2 = criterion(gru2_output, torch.randn((15, 100, 2)))
    loss_gru2.backward(retain_graph=True)
    gru2_opt.step()
    print(f"GRU1 loss: {loss_gru1.item()}, GRU2 loss: {loss_gru2.item()}")
```

With `retain_graph` set to `True` I get the error

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [100, 300]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

The error without the parameter is

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

which is expected.

Please point at what needs to be changed in the above code for it to begin training. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to put both the `optimizer.step()` at the end? Basically perform both the backward steps first with `retain_graph=True` and at the end, you can `step` both the optimizers.

Also, even for a minimal verifiable example, it might be better to declare the optimizers and the models outside the loop (for the sake of correctness and to avoid confusion).

Comment: @akshayk07 it would work, but that beats the purpose. What I am trying to do, is to update the network parameters and then sort of get a "better estimate" once `step()` is called the first time. And yes, thanks for pointing it out, I have made changes to the the MWE

Comment: @akshayk07 I am so sorry. I had missed a line. Now does it make sense? So what I am trying to do is update network 1 in the first pass and use the updated output to better network 2 in the second pass

Comment: I think you can `detach()` after using `gru1` for the second time since your 2nd optimizer only updates `gru2` i.e. needs gradients for `gru2` only.

Comment: @akshayk07 this worked, can you please put it down as an answer for me to mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, one can detach the computation graph to exclude the parameters that don't need to be optimized. In this case, the computation graph should be detached after the second forward pass with `gru1` i.e.

```
....
gru1_opt.step()
gru1_output, _ = gru1(vector)
gru1_output = gru1_output.detach()
....
```

This way, you won't "try to backward through the graph a second time" as the error mentioned.